# In a PDO prepaired statement, requesting a HAVING count > 1, what is this code doing wrong

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My code is...

```
$select_product_dups = $db->prepare("SELECT products_model FROM products GROUP BY products_model HAVING count( products_model ) > 1");
```

My editor is barking at me (at least highlighting with little info), so I figured I will check with the community on this. Everything looks to be good otherwise.

Full statement...

```
$select_product_dups = $db->prepare("SELECT products_model FROM products GROUP BY products_model HAVING count( products_model ) > 1");
$select_product_dups->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$select_product_dups->execute();
while ($select_product_dups_row = $select_product_dups->fetch()){
    $dups[] = $select_product_dups_row['products_model'];
}
```

Comment: Will you translate your editor's barks into an error message that we can understand?

Comment: No data sources are configured to run this SQL @GeorgeCummins

Comment: Could it be a PHPStorm error and the statement is just fine?

Comment: There's one way to find out... I certainly don't see anything wrong with the code as posted.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I should add, the processes to follow this query are scraping 20,000 products, with proxies tied in, making a simple echo of the results a bit overwhelming at this point. I am just getting into this as I adopted the project. My question here might have been a bit premature, but wanted to see if there was maybe an obvious to a PDO guy.

Comment: With that said, I think I need to do a bit more work on my end and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks legit to me.

No idea why your editor might be complaining, but the message you report, "No data sources are configured to run this SQL", doesn't seem related to the particulars of your statement. Have you tried replacing your query with something trivial, like `SELECT products_model FROM products LIMIT 1`? My guess is that you'll still get the warning.

Anyway, editor warnings are just eyeballing it; your SQL engine is the true judge of any query.

**Edit:** So the warning is indeed unrelated to the content of the query. My guess is that the editor can't see where you initialize the database connection (a "data source" is a database connection). Obviously it works, so I'd just ignore the warning and move on to getting the query to give you exactly what you want.

Comment: Sorry but I've got no idea what you're trying to say! Your question is about an editor warning. You think the warning has something to do with the content of your query, so I'm telling you to replace it with a simple, safe query and see whether the warning remains or disappears. If it remains (as I think it will): It's caused by something else, not by the query itself.

Comment: Ok I tried this and you are right, it is caused by something else. I will dig in some more. My other comment was that the query was not exactly doing what is was supposed to be doing(but close), I will deal with that though.

Comment: Right, those are two separate questions. Since you deleted your comment I don't know what you _were_ trying to accomplish, so I can't comment on that...

Comment: Sorry I did not want that comment to bloat this thread.. I will see if I can find more info pertaining to the question I asked initially.

Comment: Like I said, I think the warning is a non-issue: just ignore it.

Comment: So it had to do with not having the database tied into phpstorm and added plugin I am using. You directed me to the source of my problem, so thank you.